# Dismiss this job has stopped working for me

Tags: bug, jobs

I've noticed that recently if I click "Dismiss this job" then although it says I won't see this job any more it keeps reappearing on subsequent page loads.

For instance I have been dismissing this job:

[image]

... which appears to get dismissed:

[image]

... but comes right back on other page loads:

[image]